# Facebook test users unable to comment/reply on page posts. Missing comment section

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-test-users

I have created 2 test users and using 1 test user(Bob), I created a Facebook page, I'm able to use the other test user(Sally) to post on this created page that Bob made and I can reply to the post using the created page user however I am unable to comment/reply to the post using test user Sally, not even the owner of the page (Bob) can comment/reply to any posts. Is there a setting a need to change? When i do the exact same process using a live Facebook account, it works fine

Comment: You can not comment in the name of a user via API any more.

Comment: I'm not trying to do it via the API, I'm trying on Facebook it self. So I'm logging in as test user Sally and going to the page that Bob created, I can post on the page fine but I cannot comment again on this post as Sally. So Sally can only create posts but cant comment/reply

Comment: It does affect programming ability to test the work that has been done with the API's, I'm just looking for some help

Comment: as per [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users), test users cannot comment on posts.

I am having the same issue that a test user can't comment on posts with, or without the api. There doesn't appear to be any good way to test any comment related functionality in facebook unfortunately.

Comment: I found a work around, if you create multiple pages and then one the page you monitoring, create a post and then comment on the post as other pages. When you type a comment/reply, you will be n the right hand side is your pages picture, click that and just select another page, it will then allow you to comment/reply as other users.